# What is Verbose Build

Tags: c

What is a "verbose build" in C? I can's seem to find a good answer. There's a check box in Pelles C for Verbose Build and I can't figure out what this does. Does it include libraries in with the exe or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it simply spits out more messages for you during the building process.

Comment: Oh... Darn. I thought it was going to be something useful. I could use _less_ messages...

Comment: @BigEndian, you get less messages by fixing the things that cause them. :)

Comment: Haha, sometimes I go to compile and it spits out like 10 pages of errors because I missed a bracket or something. C is not super programmer friendly but I still love it :)